# Any studies on the security of different CMSs?

Tags: security, content-management-system

I like to post links to Secunia search results to demonstrate (in numbers) how insecure a certain CMS (or blogging software) is.

See [What are some of Drupal's shortcomings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447878/what-are-some-of-drupals-shortcomings#450002)

But there was an interesting comment to this answer:

[Eaton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19411/eaton):

> It's also important to note that
>   Secunia only publishes vulnerability
>   reports that are explicitly announced.
>   I've worked with other CMS packages
>   that tuck important security fixes in
>   minor releases with no announcements
>   at all. Drupal has a 15 person secteam
>   that reviews core and all 3500 addons
>   and officially announces the security
>   patches, no matter how minor, as a
>   matter of policy.

Are there any studies or articles which take this into account when comparing Content Management Systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a small number of articles bookmarked ([like this one by my coworker](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupal-and-expressionengine-security-models)), but they're almost all by people defending their CMS of choice from accusations of poor security. (My own comment in your post included!) One of the difficulties is that I don't think anyone has ironed out what constitutes a 'reasonable comparison' -- everyone gets annoyed at a bad comparison, but wanders off before anyone can determine what a level playing field is.

A couple things stand out that most "quick overviews" miss:

- The security policy of the product's dev team
- The presence of a specific person or team (depending on the project's size) responsible for security. Everyone on the project should care, obviously
- Are there documented security best practices for third-party developers
- Comparison of vulnerabilities by type and severity

Perhaps this thread would be a good place to brainstorm what WOULD constitute a good comparison study?

*Update* - A colleague has had the opposite frustration with Secunia: inaccurate and erroneous reports filed by third-parties against an OSS project. Secunia refuses to update or amend them, apparently. It's a useful service or announcements, but everything I hear makes me cringe at using them for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

The other major problem with using those Secunia searches is that they include all contributed modules along with Drupal Core even when the particular announcement even though a particular [security announcement](http://secunia.com/advisories/30934/) might be for a module that's used by [about 30 people](http://drupal.org/project/usage/tinytax).

In addition to vulnerabilities by type and severity, you also need to take into account "core" vs. "add-on" modules and the practice of occasionally putting multiple vulnerabilities into a single announcement (happens often).

My feeling is that some of Eaton's measures on policy are more important than specific numbers or severity of vulnerabilities.

The last good measure I would add to that list is months in the past X years where a vulnerability was publicly disclosed without any fix from the project.  That's rare, but is a sign of a truly failed security process.