# Discover code in web input, PHP

Tags: php, content-management-system, wysiwyg

I'm writing a basic CMS for one of my sites and have run into an issue where some pages need to dynamically serve PHP and JS, where as others are plain HTMl. I want there to be a setting which will allow this for the pages that need it and will load ACE editor instead of a different wysiwyg editor.  I want to reject any inputs that code on non-code enable pages. How do I ensure that all JS and PHP included from the database will not execute?

Comment: php code runs only the server. there's NOTHING you can do with php code in a textbox in a browser that'd make it run without heroic intervention

Comment: Only Jon Skeet can run PHP from a textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really want to do this.  Beyond the security concerns if you do things wrong, it becomes an absolute maintenance nightmare - there's no good way to put CMS pages into version control.  Testing and migrating code between development environments and live sites becomes brittle, at best.  [In one of my other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447878/what-are-some-of-drupals-shortcomings/448644#448644), I detailed the problems that come along with running a Drupal site & you're starting down a similar road.

With that said, if you insist on following through with this plan, the way to go is to use a proper template engine (I've been using [h2o](http://www.h2o-template.org/) lately) & leave the worry of escaping content to it.  The other thing I'd do would be to separate the PHP and the displayable part of the code by putting them in completely separate fields.  This not only gives you cleaner code (remember, mixing display and logic is bad) but you can **always** treat what you display as 'dumb' text and only allow it access, via the templates, to the output of your PHP.

Comment: Valid points regarding CMS. It is an unfortunate necessity since those who actively update the site do not know even basic html. (And the current site was programmed by someone who was reading "PHP for Dummies" so it can't be much less secure!).

I will check out h2o. Part of my problem is that a number of pages are generated from some old databases lying around, and the other 3/4's of it people need to be able to update from a WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: @bytewalls My complaint wasn't so much anti-CMS as it was anti-code-in-the-db.  The 2nd half of my reply focuses on keeping the risks somewhat under control.